# Is there a convenient way in ClickHouse to check the Map contains some entries

Tags: clickhouse

I want to check if a Map contains all the entries I need.

```sql
> create table map_test (my_map Map(String, String)) engine = Memory;
> insert into map_test values ({'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}), ({'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3'}), ({'k1': 'v1', 'k4': 'v4'});
> select * from map_test;
┌─my_map──────────────────────────┐
│ {'k1':'v1','k2':'v2'}           │
│ {'k1':'v1','k2':'v2','k3':'v3'} │
│ {'k1':'v1','k4':'v4'}           │
└─────────────────────────────────┘

3 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.001 sec. 


-- get the rows that "my_map" contains all entries I need.
> select * from map_test where my_map['k1'] = 'v1' and my_map['k2'] = 'v2'; -- The SQL will be very long.
┌─my_map──────────────────────────┐
│ {'k1':'v1','k2':'v2'}           │
│ {'k1':'v1','k2':'v2','k3':'v3'} │
└─────────────────────────────────┘

2 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.001 sec.
```

**If I have a lot of entries in where clause, the SQL will be very long.**

Is there a way to do it like the following SQL.

```sql
select * from map_test where mapContainsAll(my_map, {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'});
```

I've read [documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/tuple-map-functions) about Map, but can't find a function like `mapContainsAll`.

Comment: [mapContainsKeyLike](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/tuple-map-functions/#mapcontainskeylike) function was added in version [21.11](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/whats-new/changelog/2021/#clickhouse-release-v2111-2021-11-09).

Comment: @vladimir Thank you. But `mapContainsKeyLike` function can only match keys, not values.